# XML to XML conversion using XSLT 1.0 - Modifying multiple words within a text

Tags: xslt

I have been taking help from here often on various technologies. Asking question for the first time though. Recently started using XML technology at workplace. Stuck up at a crucial point. Actually I am working on XML to XML conversion using XSLT 1.0. where I came across the following issue.

The input xml looks like this:

```
<front>
<funding-group>
<award-group id="award1">
<funding-source id="GS1">A</funding-source>
<award-id rid="GS1">1</award-id>
</award-group>
<award-group id="award2">
<funding-source id="GS2">B</funding-source>
<funding-source id="GS3">C</funding-source>
<award-id rid="GS2 GS3">2</award-id>
</award-group>
</funding-group>
</front>

<body>
<p>This work was supported by the 9 Program Grant 1, A 309 and 311, and B, C Grant 2.</p>
</body>
```

I need to convert this to below (note: funding-source becomes grant-sponsor, award-id becomes grant-num and "funding-group" has been removed):

Output xml:

```
<body>
<p>This work was supported by the 9 Program Grant <grant-num>1</grant-num>, <grant-sponsor>A</grant-sponsor> 309 and 311, and the <grant-sponsor>B</grant-sponsor>, <grant-sponsor>C</grant-sponsor> Grant <grant-num>2</grant-num>.</p>
</body>
```

Tried using string-replace as well as regex but couldn't succeed fully. Really need help guys.. Help of any kind would be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For tasks like that where you need to process plain, unstructured text I would really suggest to move to XSLT 2.0 to make use of `xsl:analyze-string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 sample to be run with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="funding-group"/>

<xsl:template match="body/p//text()">
  <xsl:variable name="pattern1" select="string-join(//award-id, '|')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="pattern2" select="string-join(//funding-source, '|')"/>

  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(^|\s|[,.!?])({$pattern1})($|\s|[,.!?])">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
      <grant-num><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></grant-num>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(^|\s|[,.!?])({$pattern2})($|\s|[,.!?])">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
          <grant-sponsor><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></grant-sponsor>
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms the input

```
<root>

<front>
<funding-group>
<award-group id="award1">
<funding-source id="GS1">A</funding-source>
<award-id rid="GS1">1</award-id>
</award-group>
<award-group id="award2">
<funding-source id="GS2">B</funding-source>
<funding-source id="GS3">C</funding-source>
<award-id rid="GS2 GS3">2</award-id>
</award-group>
</funding-group>
</front>

<body>
<p>This work was supported by the 9 Program Grant 1, A 309 and 311, and B, C Grant 2.</p>
</body>

</root>
```

into the result

```
<root>

<front>

</front>

<body>
<p>This work was supported by the 9 Program Grant <grant-num>1</grant-num>, <grant-sponsor>A</grant-sponsor> 309 and 311, and <grant-sponsor>B</grant-sponsor>, <grant-sponsor>C</grant-sponsor> Grant <grant-num>2</grant-num>.</p>
</body>

</root>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This is what I needed.. Just needed to ask you whether it would work on an xml with the same context but different data and order? I mean is this code generic?

Comment: And yes I have switched to XSLT 2.0 now.

Comment: Basically the `analyze-string` looks for patterns to match your input. The patterns are generated in the above stylesheet based on `//award-id` and `//funding-source` in the input XML. So as far as that goes the code will work with different input data, as long as there are elements of that name. What is missing in my code might be a relation between `award-id` and `funding-source`, your input XML has these elements grouped together under a common parent while the string replacement I have implemented simply does a replacement matching on award-id, then one on funding-source.